# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Ruby on Rails 6 app deployment error with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Rails 6 app using the Elastic Beanstalk Ruby platform, and I'm getting a 502 when trying to access the app. The Nginx error logs have the following error...

> connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (11: Resource
> temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client:
> XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "XXX.XX.XX.XX"

What could be the issue? An exceeded resource limit?

Comment: Can you ssh into the eb instance and `curl` your app on its port and nginx on port 80 to confirm if the app works?

Comment: @Marcin excuse my n00bness, but would this just be doing a `curl` on the env-name.id.region.elasticbeanstalk.com url with :80 and :3000 (the default Rails port) appended?

Comment: From the instance it would be `curl localhost:80` and `curl localhost:3000`.

Comment: @Marcin a clue! the port 80 curl returns the 502 page, but the 3000 curl returns "Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused". Does Elastic Beanstalk not start the rails server on deploy?  thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: I see. ruby is deployed through socket. Can you try `curl --unix-socket /var/run/puma/my_app.sock http:/hi`

Comment: @Marcin I'm getting a timeout when I try that: `Connection timed out after 300013 milliseconds`

Comment: For now I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/var/log/puma/puma.log` , you may find error message such as `You have already activated puma 5.2.2, but your Gemfile requires puma 4.x` . If this is the case, make sure your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock specify version of Puma that is available on the new Amazon Linux 2 based EB platform for Ruby.